# How to assign a value from SQL Server data to a variable in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have to extract a table from SQL Server to Excel on a weekly basis.

For this purpose I am required to include a specific ID for that week in the file name.

I have created my variable, and have created a stored procedure which returns a single value every time related to the specific week we are in.

However I am unsure how I can assign that value to the variable.

Any chance anyone can help me out?

p.s. I apologize in advance if this was already answered somewhere else, Google did not help me that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. You can use the OUTPUT parameter :**

When you're using the Execute SQL Task within SSIS. You must specify that the parameter is on OUTPUT and also specify it in the Parameter mappings tab.

[image]

Create the variable `YourVariable` in your package having the type `String` and map it to the result like below:

[image]

2. **You can achieve the same result using Single Result Set :**
   It's similar to the first step of the previous solution, except that you need to set ResultSet to SingleRow :

[image]

Then, on the Result Set tab, map the first column to the variable created in the package `YourVariable` :
[image]

Comment: Awesome my friend, many thanks for the detailed walk through :)